# How to know what file fails during WPF Binding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, c#-4.0

I've read a lot of questions on SOF and links (for example http://www.beacosta.com/blog/?p=52)

But is there easy way to know what exact file I should look into when Binding fails?

If we have one Application and a lot of forms, it can be difficult too.

Comment: Bea´s post is quite comprehensive, I´m not sure what you are looking for, what is easier than looking at the output window?

Comment: There is no information, what file failed binding, what template and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking "Thrown" for the exception in question in the Debug->Exceptions menu.

E.g. if you get

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 35 : BindingExpression path error ...
```

Then you can tell the debugger to break on it by checking "Thrown" under Common Language Runtime Exceptions -> System.Data -> System.DataException. This is however, only useful if the exception originally occurs in your code. Other exceptions, such as binding to non-existing properties and so on will silently fail and only print in the Output window. There is some discussion on http://visualstudio.uservoice.com for [improving XAML debugging](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2274717-xaml-debugger)

Comment: In that case, the binding error text should be pretty self explanatory but you're right, it's a bitch finding out the exact location in the xaml source

Answer (score 0):

I just found the most WONDERFUL post when looking for this.  It is a listener that listens for binding errors and throws up a message box with details.  It only works when running from within Visual Studio, so you won't show it to your users.  Two steps - copy the class into your project, and set the listener in your main window.

http://tech.pro/tutorial/940/wpf-snippet-detecting-binding-errors

Answer (score 0):

You can use Snoop for this: http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/
Just use Snoop to point to your application and then you can sort on Binding Errors. All Bindings Errors will be highlighted in RED, and show the property of the control.